# How to set auto-scaling for kubernetes (both in same node and scale out) by using Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-pipelines, autoscaling, azure-servicebus-queues

I would like to set auto-scaling feature in Azure Pipelines for deployment of containers with Kubernetes. How can I do that if I want to auto-scaling by below rules:

> 1. depeneds on no. of messages in ServiceBus message queue
> 2. it will scale inside a node first (better to set maximum pods in node as it depends on thread no.?)
> 3. if reach maximum pods in a node, then it will scale out to use another node (can scale to use maximum pods of node as well?i.e. 3 pods for 1 node, 6 pods for 2 nodes without total 4/5 pods)

Finally, how to set by using Azure Pipelines? (above only set in Yaml file, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to scale based on number of message in the ServiceBus queue (at least native to kubernetes), that being said - you should use [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) with [Cluster Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#cluster-autoscaling). These are native kubernetes mechanisms to scale pods\cluster based on the load on the pods.

Its in preview with AKS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/autoscaler

Another approach I've seen: using cronJobs. Just start your message processors every minute with cronJobs and make them scale. this is an easy approach that requires not a lot of configuration. You can drop pod autoscaler with this approach and only use cluster autoscaler, I haven't used this approach, but it looks promising.

Comment: How about adding this?
https://github.com/torosent/kube-azure-servicebus-autoscaler

Comment: that might or might not work. this isnt part of the official kubernetes features, so... I'm not saying its bad. just saying I've never used it, i dont know if it will work for you or works at all. also, looking at the pod definition I dont think its expecting RBAC on the cluster

Comment: how about this by using Kubernetes inWebApp for Container?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394414

Comment: if this question helped you I suggest you accept it, that one is a new question I'll look at it shortly.