# How to set auto-scaling for kubernetes by using Azure Pipelines and WebApp for Container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-pipelines, autoscaling, azure-web-app-for-containers

As WebApp for Container can set Single, Multiple and Kubernetes Docker. However, I could only set Single Docker by using Deploying to WebApp for Container in Task of Azure Pipelines' Release.

Since I can set auto-scaling rule with ServiceBus message count, how can I set to use Kubernetes in Deploying to WebApp for Container in Azure Pipelines' Release?

[image: Container Settings in WebApp for Container]

[image: Releases's Tasks in Azure Pipelines]

[Reference Question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359953/)

Comment: ok, i'm not sure I understand the question, Azure WebApp != kubernetes. You can only run containers on Azure WebApp. It cannot create kubernetes objects.

Comment: I just added 2 pictures for reference. I knew Azure WebApp != Kubernetes but we can choose Kubernetes in WebApp for Container's Container Settings. So want to ask how can I set Releases' task to deploy Kubernetes to WebApp but not just deploy Single Container. Thanks.

Comment: ok, i've never seen this yet (lol). I've poked around with vsts, i dont think you can at this moment in time. the preview version doesnt even detect my linux container webapp (only detects it as a linux web app). you might be able to figure something out using webhooks. but I'm not sure, never done this